# Can I use startsWith in a switch statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have this switch statement:

```
 switch (ev.target.className) {
        case "add-li":
            newOption(ev.target.closest(".opQuestion").querySelector('ul'), false)
            break;
        case "add-starli":
            newStarSubquestion(ev.target.closest(".starQuestion").querySelector('ul'), false)
            break;
        case "add-numli":
            newNumSubquestion(ev.target.closest(".numQuestion").querySelector('ul'), false)
            break;
       case "save-li":
            saveEdits(ev.target);
            break;
        case "save-shAnli":
            saveEdits(ev.target);
            break;
        case "save-loAnli":
            saveEdits(ev.target);
            break;
        case "save-numli":
            saveEdits(ev.target);
            break;
        case "save-starli":
            saveEdits(ev.target);
            break;
        case "save-qu":
            saveEdits(ev.target);
            break;
```

We can see that if my variable is starting with `save-` it needs to execute the same code. Is there any way I can do something like this in a switch statement?

```
 switch (ev.target.className) {
        case "add-li":
            newOption(ev.target.closest(".opQuestion").querySelector('ul'), false)
            break;
        case "add-starli":
            newStarSubquestion(ev.target.closest(".starQuestion").querySelector('ul'), false)
            break;
        case "add-numli":
            newNumSubquestion(ev.target.closest(".numQuestion").querySelector('ul'), false)
            break;
       case startsWith("save-"):
            saveEdits(ev.target);
            break;
```

I am wondering if Javascript has any way that can make this work.

Comment: You could use the default case to check for `startsWith`?

Comment: If the default is not possible, you can group multiple case statements. like: `case 1: case 2: case 3: doSomething(); break;`

Comment: If those are the only way ^^ then just use If else.